# How can I select the tag-name and attributes AND values of those attributes with ONE regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the following Regular Expression from this post ([Regular expression for extracting tag attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes)).

```
(\S+)=["\']?((?:.(?!["\']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"\']))+.)["\']?
```

I've created the following PHP code and it works nicely. I get [***id='gridview1' and 'id' and 'gridview1'***] from the preg_match_all() function.

```
$regexp = '/(\S+)=["\']?((?:.(?!["\']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"\']))+.)["\']?/';
$text = '<asp:gridview id=\'gridview1\' />';

$matches = null;
preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**How should the regular expression be changed to also return 'asp' and 'gridview'?** (or 'Foo' and 'bAR' when i use:

> **<Foo:bAR />**

Comment: Did you consider using SimpleXML instead of regexp?

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems."  If you need to do anything more than the most basic analysis of HTML, use an XML parser.

Comment: In the other question, several people tried to tell you not to try to parse non-regular languages with a regular expression.  Why don't you just use one of their suggestions, where everything you ask becomes straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should not be using regular expressions to parse HTML](http://www.google.nl/search?q=do+not+use+regular+expressions+to+parse+html)

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z]+)\:([a-zA-Z]+)`  would work for something like Foo:bar

`<.*?([a-zA-Z])+.*?\:.*?([a-zA-Z])+.*?\/>` would work for < Foo   :  BArrr   />

Things can be optimized depending on your requirements and whether you know that a certain type of formatting is enforced.

Comment: I'm gonna try tomorrow to see if you're right... After that i'll be working with my XML parser ;)