# Regex & PHP - isolate src attribute from img tag

Tags: php, regex, string

With PHP, how can I isolate the contents of the src attribute from $foo? The end result I'm looking for would give me just "http://example.com/img/image.jpg"

```
$foo = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image" width="100" height="100" />';
```

Comment: @meagar - Using regex is valid (although not necessarily the most efficient route) in this limited scope.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. (Not sarcasm!)

Comment: I misspoke with the original post title and shouldn't have added regex.

I really like karim79's solution, but it requires adding a non-standard class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you don't wish to use regex (or any non-standard PHP components), a reasonable solution using the built-in [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) would be as follows:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<img src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" ... />');
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 40):

## Code

```
<?php
    $foo = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image" width="100" height="100" />';
    $array = array();
    preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $foo, $array ) ;
    print_r( $array[1] ) ;
```

## Output

```
http://example.com/img/image.jpg
```

Comment: Look out for `&amp;` entity references and numeric character references in the results!

Comment: As you wish! =) Here is a alternative syntax: `/src="(.*?)"/i`.

Comment: HTML permits use of single quotes, as long as they match. And the "alternative syntax" can match a lot more chars than expected. Finally, the `img` attribute can have spaces in the beginning and end.

Comment: it should be: `/[sS][rR][cC]\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"]/i`

Comment: @jewel why make case insensitive character classes and also write the case insensitive pattern modifier at the end? That makes no sense and makes the pattern smell.

Answer (score 9):

I got this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($img);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Assuming there is only one img :P

Answer (score 7):

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image" width="100" height="100" />');

// echo the src attribute
echo $html->find('img', 0)->src;
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

I'm extremely late to this, but I have a simple solution not yet mentioned. Load it with `simplexml_load_string` (if you have simplexml enabled) and then flip it through `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

```
$foo = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image" width="100" height="100" />';

$parsedFoo = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($foo)), true);
var_dump($parsedFoo['@attributes']['src']); // output: "http://example.com/img/image.jpg"
```

`$parsedFoo` comes through as

```
array(1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["class"]=>
    string(12) "foo bar test"
    ["title"]=>
    string(10) "test image"
    ["src"]=>
    string(32) "http://example.com/img/image.jpg"
    ["alt"]=>
    string(10) "test image"
    ["width"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["height"]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```

I've been using this for parsing XML and HTML for a few months now and it works pretty well. I've had no hiccups yet, though I haven't had to parse a large file with it (I imagine using `json_encode` and `json_decode` like that will get slower the larger the input gets). It's convoluted, but it's by far the easiest way to read HTML properties.

Comment: I did find a small issue with this last week. If an XML node has both attributes and a value, only the value is accessible with this method. I ended up having to write a simple parser that will transform simplexml into an array while keeping all data.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing, although I'm not sure about how efficient this is:

```
$imgsplit = explode('"',$data);
foreach ($imgsplit as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, 'http') !== FALSE) {
        $image = $item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this approach will run into problems if the image's URL is relative to the document, e.g. "../../img/something.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

You can go around this problem using this function:

```
function getTextBetween($start, $end, $text)
{
 $start_from = strpos($text, $start);
 $start_pos = $start_from + strlen($start);
 $end_pos = strpos($text, $end, $start_pos + 1);
 $subtext = substr($text, $start_pos, $end_pos);
 return $subtext;
}

$foo = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" 
src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image"
width="100" height="100" />';

$img_src = getTextBetween('src="', '"', $foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $html = '
        <img border="0" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
        <img border="0" src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
        <img border="0" src="/images/image3.jpg" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" />
        ';
    
    $get_Img_Src = '/<img[^>]*src=([\'"])(?<src>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i'; //for get img src path only...
    
    preg_match_all($get_Img_Src, $html, $result); 
    if (!empty($result)) {
        echo $result['src'][0];
        echo $result['src'][1];
    }
```

**for get img src path & alt text also**
then use below regex instead of above...

> <img[^>]*src=(['"])(?.+?)\1[^>]*alt=(['"])(?.+?)\2*>

```
    $get_Img_Src = '/<img[^>]*src=([\'"])(?<src>.+?)\1[^>]*alt=([\'"])(?<alt>.+?)\2*>/i'; //for get img src path & alt text also
    
    preg_match_all($get_Img_Src, $html, $result); 
    if (!empty($result)) {
        echo $result['src'][0];
        echo $result['src'][1];
        echo $result['alt'][0];
        echo $result['alt'][1];
    }
```

I got idea of that great solution from [here, PHP extract link from a href tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365753/14344959)

---

For Extract Urls of specific domains only then try below regex

```
// for e.g. if you need to extract onlt urls of "test.com" 
// then you can do it as like below regex

<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>(https?:\/\/)?test\.com.* ?)\1[^>]*>
```

Comment: Parsing valid html with regex is an unnecessary risk.

Comment: yes but If we wants to do validate the form data or manipulate the html string, then we can use regex for abstract. I used above regex in my project. so that why I share unique regex solution for abstract src path

Comment: I share solution just only for knowledge purpose only

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern:

```
'/< \s* img [^\>]* src \s* = \s* [\""\']? ( [^\""\'\s>]* )/'
```

Comment: This won't work if img is capitalized or it the title contains a '>'. It would be more robust to use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

I use **preg_match_all** to capture all images in HTML document:

```
preg_match_all("~<img.*src\s*=\s*[\"']([^\"']+)[\"'][^>]*>~i", $body, $matches);
```

This one allows more relaxed syntax of  declaration, with spaces and different quote types.

Regex reads like **<img** (any attributes like *style* or *border*) **src** (possible space) = (possible space) (' or ") (any non-quote symbol) (' or ") (anything until >) (>)

Answer (score -1):

lets assume i use

```
$text ='<img src="blabla.jpg" alt="blabla" />';
```

in

```
getTextBetween('src="','"',$text);
```

the codes will return :

```
blabla.jpg" alt="blabla"
```

which is wrong, we want the codes to return the text between the attribute value quotes i.e attr = "value".

so

```
  function getTextBetween($start, $end, $text)
            {
                // explode the start string
                $first_strip= end(explode($start,$text,2));

                // explode the end string
                $final_strip = explode($end,$first_strip)[0];
                return $final_strip;
            }
```

does the trick!.

Try

```
   getTextBetween('src="','"',$text);
```

will return:

```
blabla.jpg
```

Thanks all the same , because your solution gave me an insight to the final solution .

Comment: I do not really want to say your approach is bad, but I do think using domdocument would be a much better solution to this question. ref this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441448/how-do-i-get-the-src-attribute-of-img-tags

Comment: domdocument library is too heavy to use for such a simple task. thats like using a bulldozer to crush a snake when you have a cutlass alternative.