# How do I get the src attribute of img tags?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I load the DOM by an external url as such:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( "external_url.html" );

$arrayOfSources = array();

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( "img" ) as $image )
    $arrayOfSources[] = $image->item(0)->getAttribute("src");
```

This way I want to store all the src attributes of the img tags in an array, but I keep getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::item()`

What am I missing here? How do I extract all the src attributes from the img tags in an html?

Comment: It should be `$arrayOfSources[] = $image->item[0]->getAttribute("src");` notice the square brackets

Comment: @Kumary I don't believe that is correct. `$image` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @alex, even in that case, there is not method named `item()` in the object, AFAIK, the object he is using is composed of other objects and he needs to do away with `image(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `->item(0)` part.

---

Comment: That was the quickest (working) response I've ever seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inside that loop, you don't need to access the element with `item(0)`.

The iterator for that collection allows you to just do a `foreach()` on it and have it implicitly access each element in the [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

Comment: Correct! Moreover the error message itself tells there is no method named `item()` associated with the object, making it clear not to use it, I would have simply used the prehistoric method of `var_dump/print_r` to debug it.

Comment: On a 2nd note, I have a question here, I would have used `simplexml` here, would that have been wrong?

Comment: @Kumar: I prefer to use DOMDocument to parse HTML myself.

Comment: Any advantage? I finished a small personal project using simplexml and found it fast, but am not an expert so would like to understand why DOMDocument is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$arrayOfSources[] = $image->getAttribute("src");
```