# PHP find string of substring using Regex

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have a web page source code that I want to use in my project. I want to use an image link in this code. So, I want to reach this link using regex in PHP.

That's it:

> img src="http://imagelinkhere.com" class="image"

There is only one line like this.
My logic is to get the string between

> ="

and

> " class="image"

characters.

How can I do that with REGEX? Thank you very much.

Comment: dont use  regex to parse html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use `Regex` for HTML  .. try `DomDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```
$html = '<html><img src="http://imagelinkhere.com" class="image" /></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach ( $img as $v ) {
    if ($v->getAttribute("class") == "image")
        print($v->getAttribute("src"));
}
```

Output

```
http://imagelinkhere.com
```

Comment: The problem is, there is 30 or 40 images in this code. I want to use one of them, not all of them.

They don't have " class="image" at the end. Only one has it, and I want to use that one. That's why I said between =" and " class="image" characters, and wanted to use regex.

Comment: Can you add the fill HTML to http://pastbin.com  .. so that i can have an idea what you want .. i still belive it can be done with DomDocument

Comment: Sure, that's code. http://pastebin.com/qBN7K7xe

And that's the link I want to get:

http://i.milliyet.com.tr/YeniAnaResim/2012/12/12/ruzgar-enerjisiyle-mayini-imha-ediyor-2869627.Jpeg

Comment: just add `if ($v->getAttribute("class") == "image")` to the code

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just simpler than the headache regex.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
.*="(.*)?" .*
```

with preg replace gives you only the url in the first regex group (\1).

So complete it would look like

```
$str='img src="http://imagelinkhere.com" class="image"';
$str=preg_replace('.*="(.*)?" .*','$1',$str);
echo $str;
```

-->

```
http://imagelinkhere.com
```

Edit:
Or just follow Baba's advice and use DOM Parser. I'll remember that regex will give you headaches when parsing html with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/(http://+.*?")/",$text,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The link would be in $matches.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to do so :

1.you can use 
[SimpleHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) Dom Parser which I prefer with simple HTML

2.you can also use preg_match

```
$foo = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src="http://example.com/img/image.jpg" alt="test image" class="image" />';
$array = array();
preg_match( '/src="([^"]*)"/i', $foo, $array ) ;
```

see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I can hear the sound of hooves, so I have gone with DOM parsing instead of regex.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('path/to/your/file.html');
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
{
    if ($img->hasAttribute('class') && $img->getAttribute('class') == 'image')
    {
        echo $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
```

This will echo only the src attribute of an img tag with a `class="image"`

Answer (score -1):

Try using preg_match_all, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/img src="([^"]*)"/', $source, $images);
```

That should put all the URL's of the images in the `$images` variable. What the regex does is find all `img src` bits in the code and matches the bit between the quotes.