# match all images starting with pics.domain.com

Tags: php, regex

How can i match all images starting with `pics.domain.com`?

what i've tried

```
preg_match_all('/<img .*src=(pics.domain.com*)["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $row['story'], $matches);
```

Comment: For the zillion time, please use a HTML parser to work on HTML. Use DOMDocument to pick out the `img` tags, and then use regex to check the `src` attribute.

Comment: @nhahtdh - it does look like it's coming from a DB, but still good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) and simply iterate over each `<img>` tag; then use `parse_url()` to find the host of each image path:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($row['story']);
libxml_clear_errors();

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if (parse_url($img->getAttribute('src'), PHP_URL_HOST) === 'pics.domain.com') {
        echo "Yay, image found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, was actually typing the same thing based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag), but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

I've used the regex in the past, it works outside of `<img>` tags as well.

```
'@[\'"](https?://)?([^\.][^\'"]*?)(/)?([^\'"/]*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)[\'"]@'
```

A more specific version:

```
'@[\'"](https?://)?pics\.domain\.com[^\'"]*?\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)[\'"]@'
```

In English:

[start quote](http or https or neither)pics.domain.com(anything that isn't a quote)(some image extension)[end quote]