# Find image src with regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract `image src` from an text that only contains `img` tag?
And by the way `src` is double quote sometimes and in single quote sometimes.

Comment: no attempts yet...i was thinking to regex

Comment: Why you choose regex, what's wrong with dom parser?

Comment: i only have string that contains some description of data that may have a img element

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex & PHP - isolate src attribute from img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag)

Comment: For both quote styles try something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wV0uS7/2): `\ssrc\s*=\s*['"]\s*\K[^'"\s]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$image = '<img class="foo bar test" title="test image" src=\'http://example.com/img/image.jpg\' alt="test image" width="100" height="100" />';
$array = array();
preg_match( "/src='([^\"]*)'/i", $image, $array ) ;
print_r( $array[1] ) ;
```

Comment: this works fine but the problem is that src attr is sometimes in single quote and in that case your code does not work

Comment: If my answer works fine for you then why you did not accept my answer?

Comment: well your answer works but according to my research using REGEX for this kind of problems is not best Way.using DOMDocuments is more reliable

Comment: @ArefAnafgeh You ask about `regex` so I give you answer according to `regex`. You did mention in your question to get best way of exporting images from web. Btw `regex` is more speedy way.

Comment: your are right...i accepted your answer too.thank you again

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend using regex to parse html.  Instead you can use php's `DOMDocument()` class, which should still work even if the rest of the string isn't really html:

```
$html = 'Lorem ipsum<img src="test.png">dolor sit amet&[H*()';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgs as $img) {
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src'); 
    echo $src;
}
```

Depending on your php version you may also want to use:

```
$dom->loadHTML($a, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```