# Regex get image url for Source code

Tags: php, html, regex, image, url

- I want to get some URLs of images in Js/HTML:
  img class="img-responsive" id="Q72D2600000-MDYI" src="https://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/Guess/Q72D2600000-MDYI?$2014_G_xxlarge$" alt="Q72D2600000-MDYI" />
- Looking for solution that will detect image url. So the output will be:
  **https://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/Guess/Q72D2600000-MDYI?$2014_G_xxlarge$**

Comment: Parse the HTML and pull the `src` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex & PHP - isolate src attribute from img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120779/regex-php-isolate-src-attribute-from-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The below code may be helpfull

```
$html = '<img class="img-responsive" id="Q72D2600000-MDYI" src="https://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/Guess/Q72D2600000-MDYI?$2014_G_xxlarge$" alt="Q72D2600000-MDYI" />';
preg_match('/<img\s.*?\bsrc="(.*?)".*?>/si', $html, $matches);

$image_src = $matches[1];

echo $image_src;
```

Output

```
https://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/Guess/Q72D2600000-MDYI?$2014_G_xxlarge$
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using a Scrapebox 2.0 tool. I need one that regex to get the image URL from that source code. Is there a solution for me? Simply a reasonable regex code