# Scrape HTML for label then value in separate DIV tags

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I am scraping a database of products and I am able to get all the HTML and retrieve most values as they have some unique items. However I am stuck on some areas that have common tags.

Example:

```
<div class="label">Name:</div><div class="value">John</div>
<div class="label">Age:</div><div class="value">24</div>
```

Any ideas on how I could get those labels and associated values?

I am using HTMLAgilityPack for the rest if there is something in there that may help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Are you having trouble identifying the labels and values? Or are you having trouble matching a particular value with a particular label?

Comment: Exactly, i need to match them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the xpath to get div's with class as label and class as value

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtml);

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//This will get all div's with class as label & class value in dictionary

int cnt = 1;
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='label']"))
{
    var val = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='value'][" +  cnt + "]").InnerText;

    if(!dict.ContainsKey(node.InnerText))//dictionary takes unique keys only
    {
        dict.Add(node.InnerText, val);
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, however how can I pair them? so that label1=value1?

Comment: @JDRoberson give me 15 mins ill write it down for you

Comment: @JDRoberson please show me the code and the full error message

Comment: Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'InnerText' and no extension method 'InnerText' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\robejoha02\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\CardDB\CardDB\Form1.cs 42 63 CardDB

Line 12 of your code.

Comment: @JDRoberson my apologies their was a bug in my code i have corrected it please take updated answer

Comment: Yes working perfect. Modified it a bit to suit some other tags, but thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Int32 endingIndex;
var Name1 = GetTextBetween(yourHtml, "<div class=\"label\">", "</div><div class=\"value\">", out endingIndex);
var Value1 = GetTextBetween(yourHtml.SubString(endingIndex), "<div class=\"value\">", "</div>", out endingIndex);
var Name2 = GetTextBetween(yourHtml.SubString(endingIndex), "<div class=\"label\">", "</div><div class=\"value\">", out endingIndex);
var Value2 = GetTextBetween(yourHtml.SubString(endingIndex), "<div class=\"value\">", "</div>", out endingIndex);


public static String GetTextBetween(String allDataToParse, String startText, String endText, out Int32 indexOfEndText)
{
    var indexOfStartText = allDataToParse.IndexOf(startText);
    indexOfEndText = allDataToParse.IndexOf(endText);

    return allDataToParse.Substring(indexOfStartText, indexOfEndText - indexOfStartText).Replace(startText, String.Empty) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although XPath always sounds like a great idea, when you're scraping data you can't rely on the HTML to be well formed.  Many webpages break their HTML regularly to make scraping harder.  Even though Mark's code looks awkward, it's actually more robust in some cases.

As sad as it sounds, you can only rely on consistency in the target document when the provider has proven reliable over a long length of time.  Ideally, I'd use a regular expression to search for the tags I want specifically.  Here's a good starting point:

[Regular expression for extracting tag attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes)

Unfortunately, only you know the exact quirks of the document you're working on.  A simple solution, like the one Mark proposes, will likely work if the page you're viewing is reliable.  And frankly, it's less likely to be fragile and crash unexpectedly.

If you use the HTML document parsing code that HatSoft suggests, your program may work great on most documents, but in my experience websites will throw errors randomly, change their layout unexpectedly, or sometimes your network code will only receive a partial string.  Perhaps this is okay, but I'd suggest you try both approaches and see what is more reliable for you.