# get the href from an <A> tag in html

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hi I have some information being displayed HTML content on a web page.

Some of the content can contain:

```
<p>
<a href="/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" src="/pictures/content/images/play.jpg" style="width: 153px; height: 49px;"><br>
</a>
</p>
```

What I'm looking to do is to take the whole  tag or even just the "href" and store it in a variable...so I can display it somewhere else, (i.e. display it in a summary)

The image is always consistent so all I really need is the href.

I was thinking something like: if an  < a > tag href contains ".mp3" then get the "href"

**The < a > tag does not contain an ID or runat. It's being entered using a javascript html editor, so there's no id or runat.**

Anyone know how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: How is your HTML being generated?  Also, can you give an example of how you're trying to use the information you extract?

Comment: You might write some `php` code which will store the variable value

Comment: @GHC The html is being entered into a CMS by a user for an entire product.

Comment: @mike27015 I'm using asp.net

Comment: where do you want to use this information? in the client (i.e., javascript)? or in the server side (asp.net)?

Comment: @Mel I want to use it server side...

Comment: @mike27015, it's asp.net. see the tags in question, not php

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This expression will:

- match anchor tags which have an href attribute which ends in .mp3
- will avoid difficult html edge cases

  `<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref="([^"]*.mp3)")(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?>.*?<\/a>`

[image]

## Example

Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/CMmFQDq0qX

**Sample Text**

Note the second anchor tag has some pretty difficult edge cases which will trip up most expressions

```
<p>
<a href="/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" src="/pictures/content/images/play.jpg" style="width: 153px; height: 49px;"><br>
</a>
<a onmouseover=' href="NotTheMP3Yourelookingfor.mp3" ; if (6 > x) { funRotate(href) ; } ; ' href="/documents/content/files/DifficultToFind.mp3" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" src="/pictures/content/images/play.jpg" style="width: 153px; height: 49px;"><br>
</a>
</p>
```

**Matches**

Group 0 will have the entire `<a..>..</a>` tag
Group 1 will have just the href value

```
[0][0] = <a href="/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" src="/pictures/content/images/play.jpg" style="width: 153px; height: 49px;"><br>
</a>
[0][1] = /documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3


[1][0] = <a onmouseover=' href="NotTheMP3Yourelookingfor.mp3" ; if (6 > x) { funRotate(href) ; } ; ' href="/documents/content/files/DifficultToFind.mp3" target="_blank">
    <img alt="" src="/pictures/content/images/play.jpg" style="width: 153px; height: 49px;"><br>
</a>
[1][1] = /documents/content/files/DifficultToFind.mp3
```

Comment: Off Topic: Was that image generated based on your regex, if so, what program did you use to do it?

Comment: Yes it was generated based on my regex. I'm using http://www.debuggex.com/ . It is pretty slick and works real time as you type.

Comment: I also found this website, it's amazing

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by your tags you're using ASP.NET, therefore..

```
<a href="/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3" target="_blank"
                                              id="myAnchor" runat="server">
```

The 'runat' lets you reference it in the code behind by the 'id':

```
string href = myAnchor.HRef;
```

The string 'href' is now = "/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3", then you can break it apart as you please.

Comment: Unfortunately the a href is being generated in ckeditor so there is no id for the < a > tag ...

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Is there no way to change over to Visual Studio or such? The id/runat mechanic is pretty core to ASP.NET

Comment: Not really Sam. The < a > tag does not contain an ID or runat. It's being entered using a javascript in a html editor, so there's no id or runat.

Comment: If you're just grabbing data from an auto-generated page, then I'd probably say your best bet is just taking the page as plaintext and scouring it for anchor tags manually using string manipulation.. if you're using ckeditor to make your pages, then you'd be best switching to something that lets you specify id and runat attributes

Comment: The MatchCollection object and a suitable regex string should do the trick:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it server side, then you have two options:

A. add the runat and id attribute:

```
`<a href="/documents/content/files/my_mp3.mp3" id="myLink" runat="server" target="_blank">`
```

Then you can access the href by calling `myLink.HRef`

B. You can use an asp:Hyperlink server control instead

```
`<asp:Hyperlink NavigateUrl="yourhref.html" id="myLink" runat="server" />`
```

This will be rendered as an anchor too and you can access the href by calling `myLink.NavigateUrl`

---

EDIT:

if the link is being generated in client side, then you have to do some tinkering because this link won't be directly visible to the server code.

So first is add a hidden input control. This control will temporarily store your href so you can access it when you post back.

`<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="tempContainer" />`

then you need to run some javascript after you create the hyperlink (or before posting back). I'm using jquery in this example, but you can also use plain javascript.

```
$('.<%=tempContainer.ClientID %>').val($('.some selector to your link').attr('href'));
```

This saves your href value into the hidden input. So when you post back, you can access the value of it by calling: `tempContainer.Value`

Comment: The < a > tag does not contain an ID or runat. It's being entered using a javascript html editor, so there's no id or runat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've managed to get this:

```
        If strContent.Contains(".mp3""") Then  'check if content contains .mp3

            'find the href tag usin regex 
            Dim pattern As String = "(href=\s*\""(.+?)\"")"
            Dim html As String = strContent
            Dim href() As String = Regex.Split(html, pattern)
            Dim href1 As String = href(1) 'gets the href tag

            'make sure that this href contains contains .mp3 (and it's not some other)
            If href1.Contains(".mp3""") Then 

                'this is a hidden control to display on summary main category page                                         
                Dim atemp As hyperlink = e.Item.FindControl("lnkSound") 

                 'remove the href= and quotes from the href  

                'set the naviate url
                atemp.navigateurl = href1.Replace("href=", "").Replace(chr(34), "")
                atemp.target = "_blank"

                'make it visible as hidden for summarys that don't contain .mp3
                atemp.visible = True

            End If
        End If
```

Sorted.