# Explode white spaces in a string excluding what's inside quotes

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out how to explode white spaces in a string excluding what's inside quotes. I have found several regular expressions that can do the job, but the particularity here is that the quotes are preceded by an equal sign:

```
string = 'arg1="value1" arg2="value2" arg3="value3 value4 value5"';
```

I was able to isolate what's contained inside the quotes, but I can't get the complete pair `arg1="value1 value2"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Comment: `arg1="value1 value2"` <- there's no logic behind getting that anyway...?

Comment: In this example there's no logic indeed, but I use it to pass a label which can contain multiple words. In this case this becomes useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$test = 'arg1="value1" arg2="value2" arg3="value3 value4 value5"';
preg_match_all('#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)="([^"]+)"#', $test, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "arg1="value1""
    [1]=>
    string(13) "arg2="value2""
    [2]=>
    string(27) "arg3="value3 value4 value5""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "arg1"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "arg2"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "arg3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "value2"
    [2]=>
    string(20) "value3 value4 value5"
  }
}
```

[Sample here](https://eval.in/82159).

Comment: Mine is about the same `'~\w+(?:="[^"]+")~'` a bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
$string = 'arg1="value1" arg2="value2" arg3="value3 value4 value5"';
$whitespacearray= explode(" ",$string);
print_r($whitespacearray);
?>
```