# Remove attributes from html tags using PHP while keeping specific attributes

Tags: php, html, regex

I [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3026235/937471) to remove all tag attributes from a html string using php:

```
$html_string = "<div class='myClass'><b>This</b> is an <span style='margin:20px'>example</span><img src='ima.jpg' /></div>";
$output = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $html_string);
echo $output;
//<div><b>This</b> is an <span>example</span><img/></div>
```

But I would like to keep certain tags such as src and href. I have almost no experience with regular expresions, so any help would be really appreciated.

[maybe] Relevant update: This is parto of a process of 'cleaning' posts on a database. I am iterating through all the posts, getting the html, cleaning it, and updating it on the corresponding table.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: What's wrong with html parsers? Why you prefer regex?

Comment: There are too many ways to malform html tags that trip up regex

Comment: That was the way that got closer to what I was looking for, but I am sure open to better means.

Comment: You may be interested in another topic discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You usually should not parse HTML using regular expressions. Instead, in PHP you should call `DOMDocument::loadHTML`. You can then recurse through the elements in the document and call `removeAttribute`. Regular expressions for HTML tags are notoriously tricky.

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Examples: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/html-attributes-php

Here's a solution for you. It will iterate over all tags in the DOM, and remove attributes which are not `src` or `href`.

```
$html_string = "<div class=\"myClass\"><b>This</b> is an <span style=\"margin:20px\">example</span><img src=\"ima.jpg\" /></div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;                 // init new DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);           // load the HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//@*');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {             
    if($node->nodeName != "src" && $node->nodeName != "href") {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();                  // output cleaned HTML
```

Here is another solution using xPath to filter on attribute names instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;                 // init new DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);           // load the HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//@*[local-name() != 'src' and local-name() != 'href']");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {             
    $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();                  // output cleaned HTML
```

**Tip:** Set the DOM parser to UTF-8 if you are using extended character like this:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Instead of checking the attribute name in an if statement you can do it inside the xpath query (you will save a lot of iterations).

Comment: Thanks, this worked pretty well. I only prepended a charset because the result had some weird character formatting:
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $f->description);

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Challenge, accepted!
Multitut, thanks for that, I'll update my answer for future readers

Comment: Upvote, However your code doesn't work correctly. See [this](https://3v4l.org/Eomdi) please, and focus on `<p>` tag. The place of it isn't as expected. Can you please fix your code?

Comment: @stack. You have two choices: Either wrap all your HTML in one container (i.e. have a single root node), or allow the DOMDocument to do this for you by removing `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` as options. I hope this helps you.