# Regex pattern VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can i extract this from a website?

I know how to do web requests I just cant get my head around the regex pattern.

I want to download a file using a link and that link is in this html code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="downloadStart();window.location='http://url.co.uk/download/2690'"><button type="submit" class="css3button" value="download">Download</button></a>
```

This is the url I want `http://url.co.uk/download/2690`

Thank you any help is very grateful.

Comment: For parsing html it would probably be easier to use an html parser than regex. Html is not regular.

Comment: @multivac but even then I dont know where to start. I dont wanna be spoon fed but I am no good with regex patterns. Tried many times.

Comment: If it always has a double-quote at the end then all you need to do is get the substring up to the indexof the double-quote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes could help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

`http://url.co.uk/download/[^'"\s]+?(?=['"\s])`

This will extract all urls from the page which are the fomat: `http://url.co.uk/download/*`

Beware that this won't be limited to only anchor tags though.