# How do I import a certain selection to a text file

Tags: html, text, import, names

I have a very large file with hundreds of names. What I need is a way to import all names into a text file. This is a small part of the HTML code of a single name. In this case the name is hellostackoverflow.

```
<a class="_4zhc5 notranslate _j7lfh" title="hellostackoverflow">
```

Can you give me advice on what I should use to import every name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php and with regex the names can be imported in just few minutes. I can do this in just 10 minutes.

Comment: very interesting to know how fast you can do it

Comment: can you tell me the expression you used on regex

Comment: LOL Fraxous.. sorry i was working on the other thing let me find the regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Comment: Please check this.