# regular expression to get html tag value

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML string`<img class='left' alt='&quot;&quot;' src='182-35622' title='MyImage_147x91.png' uri='182-35622' style='width: 147px; height: 91px;'>`
How to get the "title" value from regular expression using javascript only.

I want output should be "MyImage_147x91.png"

any suggestions?

i tried so far it's not working

```
 var htmlString = "<img class='left' alt='&quot;&quot;' src='182-35622' title='MyImage_147x91.png' uri='182-35622' style='width: 147px; height: 91px;'>"

 var setCookieMetaRegExp = /<img title=[\"'](.*)[\"'].*>/ig;

 var matches = [];

while (setCookieMetaRegExp.exec(htmlString)) {
  //matches.push(RegExp.$1);
}
```

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse html.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for extracting tag attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes)

Comment: There are so many questions already on this exact topic.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just get the node and do `node.title`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use HTML DOM information to obtain image title?

```js
var img = document.querySelector('img.left');
console.log(img.title);
```

```html
<img class='left' alt='&quot;&quot;' src='182-35622' title='MyImage_147x91.png' uri='182-35622' style='width: 147px; height: 91px;'>
```

If you really need to use regex on the string try below:

```js
var s = "<img class='left' alt='&quot;&quot;' src='182-35622' title='MyImage_147x91.png' uri='182-35622' style='width: 147px; height: 91px;'>";
var regex = /title\s*=\s*'([^']*)/;
console.log(regex.exec(s)[1]);
```

Regex [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YlkF2h/1) with explanation

Answer (score 0):

You should [avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Instead, use the `getAttribute` method:

```
const img = document.querySelector('.left');
img.getAttribute('title'); // => MyImage_147x91.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
title='([^']+)'
```

Use [this](https://regexone.com/) website to learn regex. Though based on the other answers to this question there are better ways to go about doing this.