# Regular Expression to get all words before a single certain character (=, with or without whitespaces before)

Tags: php, regex

We are offering some template engine to our customers on our portal. Attributes getting replaced with information from a data source.

Here's an example of how such template might look like, with different variations of quotes and whitespaces, nestings here and there:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Some Title</h1>
        <div id="output">
            [%if findthis1='123']
                Bla bla bla ["findthis2"] Bla Bla Bla
            [%elseif (findthis3 = "123")]
                Bla Bla Bla ['findthis4'] Bla Bla Bla
            [%elseif ( findthis5 = "123" )]
                Bla Bla Bla [findthis6] Bla Bla Bla
            [%elseif (   findthis7   =   "123" OR findthis8   =   123   )    AND       findthis9='123']
                [findthis10] Bla Bla Bla
            [%elseif ( findthis11 = "123" OR ( findthis12=123 AND findthis13='123' ) ]
                 Bla Bla Bla [findthis14]
            [%endif]

            [%uppercase findthis15]
            [%lowercase findthis16 ]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Our goal is to get all words before the character `=` between `[%` and `]` where whitespaces might occur.

We stumbled upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes1), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/317081/3033043), but since it is made to find html attributes, we couldn't manage to reduce the pattern down to parts between  `[%` and `]`. And also, once there's a whitespace between the attribute and the `=`, it does not match anymore.

How should we modify the regular expression as seen in the thread/answer to get the attributes like ***findthis1/3/5/7/8/9/11/12/13*** without getting ***class*** and ***id***, considering anything between  `[%` and `]` and with possible whitespaces? As for attributes findthis15 and findthis16 where there is no `=`, we would like to find another regular expression for that.

EDIT: I forgot to mention 2 things:

- findthis-Attributes can be anything like "email" or "firstname"
- There are also Operators like <=, >= and !=

EDIT 2: Right now, I am thinking about using multiple regular expressions. First one would be `\[\%(.)*\]`, which would get me all lines starting with [% and ending with ]. I am trying to figure out the next regular expression to check if there are operators in it, or if it is one of these lines like `[%uppercase findthis15]`.

EDIT 3: 2nd Regular Expression of 3 would look like this this:

```
(\S+)+[\ ]*((=|<>|!=))
```

EDIT 4: Okay, after some experimenting, we still couldn't manage to improve the regular expression to achieve our goals.

By using `/\[\%(if|elseif)(.)*?(\])/`, we are getting something like this (please ignore the fact that I am using a different line compared to the ones above):

```
[%if hello="abc" OR ( (stack=123 AND overflow = "bla") OR (how= 'bla' AND are ='bla') AND you = 'xyz' )]
```

But now, the final step is to get the words "hello", "stack", "overflow", "how", "are" and "you" by using PHP's preg_match function.

The following (wrong) regular expression is way too greedy:

```
(\ |\()+(?:(?!(=|<|&lt;|>|&gt;|<=|>=|<>|&lt;&gt;|!=)).)*
```

What are we missing in this final regular expression?

Comment: Adding an example of expected results would help understand your question. Is it all the `findthis` words? If so, your question seems to refer only to some of them (before `=`), while your code contains others such as `[%uppercase findthis15]`.

Comment: @El_Vanja These findthis-Attributes can be anything, like "email", "gender", "firstname", "lastname", etc. Like I mentioned in the last sentence, we would write a different regular expression for "non-operator statements" like ``[%uppercase findthis15]``.

Comment: The EDIT4 regex is simple, `\w+(?=\s*=)` or `\w[^=\s]*(?=\s*=)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, thank you so much. I just tried the first of both solutions you mentioned and it looks like it is working nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the last step that you have already arrived at, you may use

```php
\w[^=\s]*(?=\s*=)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ax95Zl/2/)

*Details*:

- `\w` - a word char (letter, digit or `_`)
- `[^=\s]*` - zero or more chars other than a `=` and whitespace
- `(?=\s*=)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then a `=` char.